# Combination of group_by and select in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have checked the group_by function to select mean disp of one cylinder type in mtcars, but it's not giving me the right answer. See below;

```
summarise(group_by(mtcars,cyl), mean(disp))
```

Output:

```
> summarise(group_by(mtcars,cyl), mean(disp))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl `mean(disp)`
  <dbl>        <dbl>
1     4         105.
2     6         183.
3     8         353.
```

But

```
summarise(group_by(mtcars,cyl = 6), mean(disp))
```

Output:

```
> summarise(group_by(mtcars,cyl = 6), mean(disp))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
    cyl `mean(disp)`
  <dbl>        <dbl>
1     6         231.
```

Note: I wanted to get the same answer for cylinder type 6 as per the first code. But the answers are different.

Answer (score 3):

You can't get the same answer:
This is because n and sum is changing whether you `group_by` `cyl` or you `group_by` `cyl= 6`. Therefore the mean is different:
See this example, mainly look and the n and sum as mean is sum/n:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl = 6) %>% 
  summarise(mean(disp), n=n(), sum_disp=sum(disp), Mean2 = sum_disp/n)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(mean(disp), n=n(), sum_disp=sum(disp), Mean2 = sum_disp/n)
```

Output:

```
> mtcars %>% 
+   group_by(cyl = 6) %>% 
+   summarise(mean(disp), n=n(), sum_disp=sum(disp), Mean2 = sum_disp/n)
# A tibble: 1 x 5
    cyl `mean(disp)`     n sum_disp Mean2
  <dbl>        <dbl> <int>    <dbl> <dbl>
1     6         231.    32    7383.  231.
> mtcars %>% 
+   group_by(cyl) %>% 
+   summarise(mean(disp), n=n(), sum_disp=sum(disp), Mean2 = sum_disp/n)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
    cyl `mean(disp)`     n sum_disp Mean2
  <dbl>        <dbl> <int>    <dbl> <dbl>
1     4         105.    11    1156.  105.
2     6         183.     7    1283.  183.
3     8         353.    14    4943.  353.
```

Comment: Okay, I understood the difference. Thank you!

Comment: Why is `n()` changing? Its because `cyl=6` creates a column called cyl and all the values in it are just 6. So technically doing the sum/mean of all the points in the dataset.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for comparison operator which is `==` and not `=` and it should be used within `filter`. `cyl = 6` would just change all the `cyl` values to 6 and is returning you mean for all the `disp` values i.e `mean(mtcars$disp)`.

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(mean_disp = mean(disp)) 

#  cyl mean_disp
#1   4  105.1364
#2   6  183.3143
#3   8  353.1000

mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl == 6) %>%
  summarise(mean_disp = mean(disp))

#  mean_disp
#1  183.3143
```

Comment: Okay, I have got the answer successfully by making the changes as  filter(cyl == 6). Thanks for the guidance.